# Prevent click event and wait for CSS transition to finish

Tags: jquery, css, click, transition

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gXSP/)

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('p').removeClass('hidden').delay(1000).queue(function(next) {
        $(this).addClass('hidden');
        next(); 
    });
});
```

I'd like to use CSS transitions and jQuery's delay functionality to have some text fade in, then fade out after a set time. The problem is that if I click the button multiple times, it set's up multiple delay's and the click event is all screwy. I can no longer predict when the text will fade out. Is there a way I can prevent the click event from propagating until the full transition (fade in, delay, then fade out) has finished?

Comment: `if($('p').is(':not(.hidden)')) return;` see if it fits your needs: http://jsfiddle.net/9gXSP/3/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**.one()**](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to bind click

```
var myfunction = function (){
    $('p').removeClass('hidden').delay(1000).queue(function(next) {
        $(this).addClass('hidden');
        next(); 
        $('button').one('click', myfunction);
    });
}
$('button').one('click', myfunction);
```

### OR

You can use [**.off()**](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to unbind event

```
var myfunction = function (){
    $('button').off('click');
    $('p').removeClass('hidden').delay(1000).queue(function(next) {
        $(this).addClass('hidden');
        next(); 
        $('button').on('click', myfunction);
    });
}
$('button').on('click', myfunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this condition :

```
if($('p').queue())
```

Like that :

```
$('button').click(function(){

    if($('p').queue()) $('p').removeClass('hidden').delay(1000).queue(function(next) {
        $(this).addClass('hidden');
        next(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: good one, never thought of that one. But don't we need to `.clearQueue()` inside queue() callback

Comment: @A.Wolff thank, but i think your way (with `:hidden`) is better since the CSS animation will be completed.